# Java: Hashmap of Enum subset elements

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, enumeration

I have a large enum in Java and I want to break it down into subsets (I think I can do this with EnumSet). I then want to be able to create a hashmap or enummap of **only** the elements in the EnumSet. How can I achieve this please?

```
public enum Test { ENUM1, ENUM2, ENUM3, ENUM4, ENUM5 }

EnumSet<Test> testSet = EnumSet.range(ENUM2, ENUM4);

HashMap<testSet, String> testHashMap;        <--- Compilation Failure
```

***Edit:***
I want to be able to create the hashset to only have Keys for the available enums of the EnumSet and assign a unique string value to each enum in the EnumSet.

Thanks!

Comment: `testSet` isn't a type. Does `HashMap<EnumSet<Test>, String>` work?

Answer (score 1):

`testSet` is an instance of the `EnumSet`. You want to define the key type to be `EnumSet<Test>` instead:

```
HashMap<EnumSet<Test>, String> testHashMap = new HashMap<>();
...
testHashMap.put(testSet, "string");
```

Comment: I want to be able to create the hashset to only have Keys for the available enums of the EnumSet and assign a unique string value to each enum in the EnumSet.

Comment: @user3469157 You should put this requirement in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a `HashMap<Test, String>`, and you're going to have to enforce the restriction to the specified range yourself.  You can't encode that restriction at the type system level in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get compile time checking as in your example - unless you actually split the enum into multiple smaller enums. At runtime there are some options.

If possible, I would create an [unmodifiable view of a map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html?is-external=true#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29) `EnumMap<Test, String>`. This essentially restricts the map keys to whatever Enum constants you choose.

The actual map is still mutable. If the strings need to change under your control, you can do that internally but only make the immutable map public.  If everyone needs to be able to change the strings, you could use something like an unmodifiable `EnumMap<Test, StringHolder>` and pre-fill it with the the desired enum ranges and and empty holder (`StringHolder` is a simple pogo, with getter and setter for a single string value. Kind of like a mutable string).

Another option would be to your your own Map type (backed by a `HashMap` or `EnumMap`). Whenever a new key is created, check `testSet` and throw an exception if the key isn't in there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to extend `HashMap` unfortunately. Each time an element is added, you'll have to check it against an EnumSet.

```
public class EnumSetMap<E, V> extends HashMap<E, V> implements Map<E, V> {
    private EnumSet<E> allowed;

    public EnumSetMap(EnumSet<E> allowed) {
        this.allowed = allowed;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(E key, V value) {
        if (allowed.contains(element))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key must be in the Enum set.");
        return super.put(E, V);
    }
}
```

Your example code would become:

```
HashMap<Test, String> = new EnumSetMap<Test, String>(testSet);
```